# Failed to get parameters after launching .launch file from another .launch file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have .launch (turtlebot3.launch) file in which I am launching a node, that needs parameters. I take parameters as argument in launch file (turtlebot3.launch) such as `x`, `y`, `radius` etc under node `/spawn`. I am launching this file multiple times with other launch file (multi_robots.launch).

```
<group ns="$(arg robot1)">
    <include file="$(find path_planning)/launch/turtlebot3.launch">
        <arg name="robot" value="$(arg robot1)"/>
        <arg name="radius" value="0.08"/>
        <arg name="x" value="5."/>
        <arg name="y" value="6."/>
        <arg name="theta" value="0."/>
        <arg name="x_goal" value="6."/>
        <arg name="y_goal" value="2."/>
        <arg name="theta_goal" value="0."/>
        <arg name="robot_color" value="[50,50,50]"/>
        <arg name="laser_color" value="[0,255,0]"/>
    </include>
</group>
```

Basically, args passed here above are parameters for another launch file.

Now there are parameters for robot1/spawn such as `x`, `y`, `radius`. But when I try to get parameters

```
rospy.get_param('/robot1/spawn/radius')
```

It raises `KeyError: '/robot1/spawn/radius'`

They are not shown in the `rosparam list` either.

I am not sure If something like this is possible or not. If not, is there any suggestions I can try?
I need parameters(mainly radius and start) for each robots in one node.

ROS noetic,
Python3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376393/failed-to-get-parameters-after-launching-.launch-file-from-another-.launch-file?/) by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2021-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was noticed that spawn was being shut down before I access the parameters from `/spawn` due to that I was unable to catch the relative parameters of spawn node. As a solution, I defined same parameters under node I was using that parameter. I am passing these parameters as arguments in other launch file, It was just a small edit in launch file.
Thank you @gvdhoorn for direction.

---

Originally posted by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) with karma: 328 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0